# Can I use "npm desktop-screenshot" on Ubuntu Server to create a screen shot?

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, express, screenshot

I'm running a nodejs server on Ubuntu server on Azure Microsoft, I need to create a screen shot of my desktop, whenever I call the api. I'm using the nodejs express api to run this library "desktop-screenshot", but it's not working. BTW it works on my localhost MacOS. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [desktop-screenshot source code](https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot/blob/master/capture/linux.js), it uses Scrot under the hood.

```
var scrot = childProcess.spawn(path.join(__dirname, "bin", "scrot", "scrot"), [options.output]);
    scrot.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        try {
            fs.statSync(options.output);
            callback(null, options); // callback with options, in case options added
        }
        catch(error) {
            callback("file_not_found", null);
        }
    });
```

Scrot requires certain X Server configurations (and X Server running of course). Check whether you have X Server.

If you don't want X Server, you can use [snapscreenshot](https://superuser.com/questions/1162460/cli-screenshot-no-x-server).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm using the Ubuntu 16.04. How can I setup the X server? And the x server configuration? I tried to install it by following this link: https://esc.sh/blog/install-gui-ubuntu-server/, Could you provide me a correct way to setup the X server? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you check whether you have XServer running?

Disclaimer!, I haven't done tried this. But the article at https://blog.codeanywhere.com/setup-a-x11-desktop-on-your-devbox-openvz-container/ seems promising.